# Openfire server not saving chatroom to the ofMucRoom table

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I'm developing and iOS chat app and using openfire server. After successful research I managed to create a room. The room I'm creating is persistent and I can see that room listed in Group Chat tab in open fire and is also persistent. But when I open my mysql database I cant see any entry in the mucRoom table. Plus mucMember table is also empty.

Even using spark client I cant login to the room created as it always says Connecting... On the iOS side I get the response in xml as "Room Locked until configuration is confirmed".

In the openfire admin when I edit the newly created room and save it back again, it appears in db and I'm then able to send/receive msgs using Spark client.

What is the problem? Why openfire is not saving the room to db from its cache? Even there is no such setting in openfire. This is the major issue all where and I can't find a proper answer to it. Anybody with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS client response is telling you the issue.  A room's settings must be confirmed by the room creator.  Until that time, it is locked, and you will continue to see that message.  The process of room creation is outlined [here](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom).

My client application uses the iOS/OSX XMPPFramework, and my Openfire server is configured to create "Instant Rooms".  XMPPFramework makes room creation and confirmation extremely simple.  By adding XMPP Room delegate to a stream, you get a delegate callback when a user sends their presence to a room that does not exist yet.  At which point, you can confirm the room settings or modify them appropriately.

```
#pragma mark XMPPRoom Delegate

- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    [self.xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil]; //nil confirms the default settings
}

- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppRoomDidLeave:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender occupantDidJoin:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender occupantDidLeave:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message fromOccupant:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}
```

I have not looked into the details of when a room is persisted, but I have also noticed in my use case that there is a discrepancy in the rooms displayed in the admin page from what is in the database.